# Question about coordinate change

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus, derivatives

Say $f$ is a function $f: \mathbb R^2 \to \mathbb R$. Can someone show me an example of such an $f$ with the property that $(\partial / \partial x)^2 f(x,y) = 0$ and $(\partial / \partial y)^2 f(x,y) = 0$ in one example of coordinates and $(\partial / \partial x)^2 f(x,y) \neq 0$ and $(\partial / \partial y)^2 f(x,y) \neq 0$ in another? Is it possible?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Take $f(x,y)=xy$. Then both pure second partial derivatives are 0, but if we change coordinates to $x=u+v$, $y=u-v$, then $f=(u+v)(u-v)=u^2-v^2$, which has non-zero pure second partials.

Comment: Great example, thank you!